Automatic on and off light strip
I am trying to make an led strip turn on and off automatically based on sunlight. So when it is dark the lights will be on full brightness and when it is daytime the lights would be off. The led strip is dimmable, it is starting working voltage is 16.5vdc to 24vdc.
My LDR is 3K to 200K (Dark). LED strip is 24VDC, 0.6A for the length I am using.

How can that be achieved?
The output is never 24VDC no matter how dark it gets, the maximum i could get it is 17.9VDC

Hi Fatema! Welcome here; when you look in your browser window, you see a lot of "Related" links to the right that answer your question of how to approach things. I'm just linking to the first few– you can do a lot more research and find solutions on here :)

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630957/how-do-i-control-the-sensitivity-range-of-an-ldr-controlled-led?rq=1 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/677900/using-an-ldr-and-pnp-transistor-to-automatically-dim-12-v-common-anode-7-segment?rq=1

I know, i have already done two circuits, one with NE555 and the other with transistors. All circuit are being done using 9V battery or 12VDC. My light strip is 24VDC, this is why i want to know how to calculate the values of resistors. No one explains how they are calculated.

NE555 timers cannot handle 24VDC.

Ah, so you have a lot of work already! Please include that (especially schematics) in your question! I don't know which resistors you mean – there's a lot of ways you can connect LEDs to a 555, and most sensible methods would use both an external transistor, base or gate resistors, and series resistors for the LEDs; without knowing what the system you're currently going for looks like, we can't really help you. So: please include the schematic of your 555 circuitry in your question. Then, be specific about what you need help with – it seems you already have a lot of specific knowledge!

How much current does the LED strip consume at 24 VDC? That will help to design how to switch the LED strip on or off.

4.8W per meter, i will be using almost 3 meters so the current required is 0.6A

That circuit doesn't even work for the purpose illustrated in the instructable you link to. It tries to draw all the current for the LED strip from the output of the NE555. That can supply a few hundred mA, but the length of strip they attach draws much more. You should really look through the links I've posted. And as said, you'll need an external transistor.

I am only testing the transistors method at the moment as it makes more sense. I supplied it with 24VDC and it works alright. However, it is not bright enough. I am trying to change the 10k values. This is why i am looking for the formula to calculate the resistors values instead of varying the resistors. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/653615/transistor-bc547-and-led-diode-like-light-sensor-to-work-properly

You should add the actual schematic you're using to the question and show all the component values so we can help you get the right result. Also be clear about what you want - is it lights either on or off, or dimming up and down in response to the daylight?

Schematic added. But with reference to the previous posts I have included.

Two things stand out immediately. A BC547 is not capable of carrying 0.6A, you need something capable of carrying at least 1A for safety. And are you sure your LED strip needs that 10 Ohm resistor (R4)? Normally they are powered directly by DC. Though R4 is probably preventing the transistor from being destroyed at the moment by limiting the brightness.

It is not really needed. What would you suggest for a transistor ?

The 2N2222 might suit better but i will require more. BC517 would be better ? With 1.2A
